# Get timestamp of beginning of day given 'Y-m-d'

Tags: php

Given a date string formatted `Y-m-d` (`2014-4-11` for example), how can I get a UNIX timestamp of 12am the beginning of that day? Would it involve `date_parse_from_format()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `strtotime()`

```
$date = "2014-04-11";
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
```

which inturm gives you -

```
$d = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);  // 2014-04-11 00:00:00
```

Try online conversion to test - http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, I'm looking to output a UNIX timestamp (seconds since Jan 1st, 1970)

Comment: Yes. Then can simply echo $timestamp above. It'll give you UNIX Timestamp of the date.